# How To Create Lossless Progressive JPG/JPEG Images with Gulp

Tags: gulp, jpeg, gulp-imagemin

I am trying to optimize the images using gulp and came across following plugins which can help me in this.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-jpeg-recompress

But when I try to optimize the jpeg and make them progressive through it the output image is not equal in quality(colour, clarity) as that of the original. 
I have tried the max, min quality (100) in the #2 plugin but still the quality is degraded. I am not sure where it is going wrong.

```
// This degrades the quality of Image
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
    var imageminJpegRecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress');

    gulp.task('optimize', function () {
      return gulp.src('src/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
          use:[imageminJpegRecompress({
            progressive: true,
            min: 100,
            max: 100,
            quality:'veryhigh' 
          })]
        }))
    });

// This degrades the quality of Image
    var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
    gulp.task('image1', function () {
        return gulp.src('Content/img/**/*.jpg')
            .pipe(imagemin({
                progressive: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));       
    });
```

If someone knows any other plugin for optimizing  and creating progressive images without degrading the quality? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What if you just use `imagemin` for this, e.g.: https://gist.github.com/divspace/bda6196a0a0d55120c9a

Comment: @KyleAnderson I tried that as well. It degrades the quality of Image. I want the JPEG to be progressive and optimized to an extent where it should look as good as the original image.

Comment: `gulp-imagemin` is a "lossless" converter by nature, but I am seeing color conversion when testing with https://photoflurries.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/img_4576.jpg.  The original color information is not preserved, and you can see subtle color differences

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [`gulp-gm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gm), which uses a more robust graphics library (GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick) and will preserve the color profiles.  The script below will create a progressive image using the "Line" value as specified in [the `interlace()` documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-interlace)

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gm = require('gulp-gm');

gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/images/**/*')
    .pipe(gm(function (gmfile) {
      return gmfile.interlace('Line')
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
})

gulp.task('default', ['images'])
```

Note the installation instructions for your system provided on https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gm.  I installed GraphicsMagick on a Mac, so ensure you have the graphics library installed first